Can I automatically delete/clear Pulsar topics when there are no more consumers?
I'm making a multiplayer game in Go. When you enter a room name, it will connect to a Pulsar topic with that name. When you enter a player name, it creates a subscription to that topic with that name. Each player creates a producer on that topic and a consumer on their subscription. When they leave the game their consumer will unsubscribe and they will close their consumer and producer.
I believe I need a persistent topic as players who join later than others should still consume the earlier messages in that game. However, I would like for the topic to clear all the messages if everyone leaves the game. I've found that for example, if you play a game and then come back next week and join the same room name, you will consume all the messages from the last game too. I would like it to instead "start a new game". I am able to go into my StreamNative console and manually delete the topic between each game of course, but I would like the topic to delete or clear itself automatically once all the players leave. Is this possible?

apache pulsar has some configuration for this, the relevant configurations are as follow:
# Enable topic auto creation if new producer or consumer connected (disable auto creation with value false)
allowAutoTopicCreation=true

# Enable the deletion of inactive topics. This parameter need to cooperate with the allowAutoTopicCreation parameter.
# If brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsEnabled is set to true, we should ensure that allowAutoTopicCreation is also set to true.
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsEnabled=true

# How often to check for inactive topics
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsFrequencySeconds=60

# Set the inactive topic delete mode. Default is delete_when_no_subscriptions
# 'delete_when_no_subscriptions' mode only delete the topic which has no subscriptions and no active producers
# 'delete_when_subscriptions_caught_up' mode only delete the topic that all subscriptions has no backlogs(caught up)
# and no active producers/consumers
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsMode=delete_when_no_subscriptions

# Metadata of inactive partitioned topic will not be cleaned up automatically by default.
# Note: If `allowAutoTopicCreation` and this option are enabled at the same time,
# it may appear that a partitioned topic has just been deleted but is automatically created as a non-partitioned topic.
brokerDeleteInactivePartitionedTopicMetadataEnabled=false

# Max duration of topic inactivity in seconds, default is not present
# If not present, 'brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsFrequencySeconds' will be used
# Topics that are inactive for longer than this value will be deleted
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsMaxInactiveDurationSeconds=
        

and all of these configuration are dynamic(you can check in broker configuration) , which means you can update these configurations without restarting the service, wish this can help.

Do you know how I can access the configuration from the go client? The documentation says to look in the conf folder of the installation, but I don't have an installation. Currently I am just importing "github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go/pulsar" at the top of my file.

Maybe you can check out this Pulsar Admin Rest API document，which you can use http or https requests to change broker dynamic config. of course if the cluster has an authentication then request it needs to add authentication
